# failed bootstrapping: TypeError: Cannot redefine property: local using aws-cdk-local with localstack

Tags: localstack

I am using aws-cdk and aws-cdk-local with localstack.
Before, all commands were working fine, after a boot, localstack starts fine, but when using commands like

```
cdklocal bootstrap
cdklocal deploy
```

throws following error

> Bootstrapping environment aws://000000000000/us-east-1...
> Environment aws://000000000000/us-east-1 failed bootstrapping: TypeError: Cannot redefine property: local
> at Function.defineProperty ()

I have try re-installing packages, localstack.

Answer (score 0):

After deletion of ~/.aws/config file. Commands works perfectly.

To remove file using command

```
$ sudo rm -rf ~/.aws/config
```